# Dependency Resolution Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

I am doing Unit Testing  In my Project.When I try to unit test my method a browser pops up and suddenly gets stopped after that I get a long exception I pasted following.
How to fix this mess as I have no idea whats the cause?

**Exception:**

https://paste.ubuntu.com/24389202/

**BrowseHost Class**

```
 public static class BrowserHost
    {
        public static readonly SelenoHost Instance = new SelenoHost();
        public static readonly String RootUrl;
         static BrowserHost()
        {
            Instance.Run("BankingSite", 1468);
            RootUrl= Instance.Application.Browser.Url;
        }
    }
```

**UnitTest Class**

```
namespace BankingSite.FunctionalUITests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LoanApplicationTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldAcceptLoanApplication()
        {
            BrowserHost.Instance
                .Application.Browser
                .Navigate()
                .GoToUrl($@"{BrowserHost.RootUrl}\LoanApplication\Apply");

            var firstNameBox = BrowserHost.Instance.Application
                .Browser
                .FindElement(By.Id("FirstName"));
            firstNameBox.SendKeys("Gentry");

            var lastNameBox = BrowserHost.Instance.
                Application.
                Browser.
                FindElement(By.Id("LastName"));
            lastNameBox.SendKeys("Smith");

            var ageBox = BrowserHost.Instance
                .Application
                .Browser
                .FindElement(By.Id("Age"));
            ageBox.SendKeys("40");

            var incomeBox = BrowserHost.Instance
                .Application
                .Browser
                .FindElement(By.Id("AnnualIncome"));
            incomeBox.SendKeys("9999999");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            var applyButton = BrowserHost.Instance
                .Application
                .Browser
                .FindElement(By.Id("Applt"));

            applyButton.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            var acceptMessageText = BrowserHost.Instance
                .Application
                .Browser
                .FindElement(By.Id("acceptMessage"));

            Assert.That(acceptMessageText, Is.EqualTo("Congratulations Gentry - Your Application was accepted!"));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

        }
    }
```

**Following is the Screen Shot of URL I am browsing directly.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from what you've provided, but there is a clue in the stack trace:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'BankingSite.FunctionalUITests.BrowserHost' threw an exception.
>     ----> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. ---> Not a Number (See inner exception for details.)
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Not a Number

Check the constructor for `BankingSite.FunctionalUITests.BrowserHost` and see if you can find the line that is causing the error.  Apparently it is expecting a numeric value but received something else instead.

Comment: Actually I am following a Pluralsight Code and I am following same line of code.A weird thing that is happening is that whenever I try to run my test my firefox browser pops us and then it stops suddenly?

Comment: Since the class is called `BrowserHost` I'm going to guess that this specific UI test attempts to start a browser and access a page.  So that part isn't so unexpected.

Comment: Yes John browser should pop up and automate some logic like entering some text box values.What unexpected is the way It stopped suddenly after being launched? I guess actually the application "BankingSite" is not getting called by my unit test project.I tried to run BankingSite as a standalone project and It is working fine?

Comment: It stopped because of the exception.  You have to fix the exception.  I can't tell you what is causing it without seeing the code that raises the exception. If I had to guess, there is some setup config that has a bad value in it somewhere.

Comment: John code is large what specific part of it should I post here?

Comment: The constructor for `BankingSite.FunctionalUITests.BrowserHost`.  But before you post it, maybe you could step through it with a debugger and see if you can figure it out..